new rockshox boxxer select rc from 2023 YT Tues core 2 has oil on right stanchion after first DH ride and being stored upside down for a week
As title states I purchased a 2023 YT tues core 2 last autumn. Took it for a couple of easy flat rides just to make sure it was feeling good. Everything seemed fine. Took it to the park last week and afterwards left it stored upside down for a week. Went to clean it and found oil on the stanchion. I have attached a video of the stanchion. Is this a tolerable amount of oil to lose and is this normal for a boxxer? I would prefer not to have to run it through a shop or warranty as the biking season just started last week. It did not appear to bottom out while at the park.
Video: https://youtube.com/shorts/Fx9pVPL-Odo?feature=share

I generally agree with mattnz's answer, but wanted to add some thoughts.  First, regarding the amount of oil.  Under the circumstances of the fork being stored upside down and undergoing it's first robust outing as a new fork, the amount of oil seen on the stanchion is not what I would call abnormal, AT THIS POINT.  If every outing the stanchion is coming back with that much oil, that hints to a problem. My forks, after a lowers service will have a noticable smear of oil and slick honey on the stanchions the first couple days post service. When I've stored the bike upside down for overnight in anticipation of a big ride the next day, I'll see some extra shine on the stanchions (and they do feel better. Less stiction certainly).
One thing that needs to be determined is the cause of those streaks on the front coming up from the seal to about the first line of oil. I believe this is the reflection mattnz refers to initially in his answer.  I don't like the looks of it on the video. It's as if perhaps some sand grains have gotten stuck in the seal or foam rings and causing a couple point areas of wear. In short, you don't want to see streaks on your stanchions like that. It infers the seal not having uniform compression on the stanchion. Either because of foreign object or damage to the seal. If these streaks are real and not an illusion of light shine, immediate action is advisable.
What I would do depends on the streak evaluation. If those were not present, I would continue to ride the fork and note the amount of oil accumulating after the rides. At this point, that amount of oil is normal I'd say, but that much oil continuing to be seen every ride is a problem and the seals need to be changed with a lowers service. Should I examine the stanchion and determine the streaking is actually present, I would not ride the fork until I performed a lowers service and took a good look at the inner surface of the seals and likely replace them and the foam rings.

Took it to the shop today and they said that it should have the oil replaced just to be sure that there was plenty of oil in it but it has a good chance of being from oil used on the seals. They said to ride it at the park and if it starts to feel bad or leak oil to bring it back and start looking at warranty. The streaks are a mixture of a reflection and some grime on the wipers, not present after cleaning. I will likely be looking into pulling the lowers and refilling the oil in the near future either way, just to be safe.

Good plan. Bath oil requirements are lower than they used to be.  There's anecdotal evidence online that there can be less oil than required from a new fork fresh from the factory. Sometimes much less. Accompanied by the tremendous amount of excess factory applied grease on the air side, new fork owners, including myself, have taken to completing a lowers service out of the box.  My 2021 Fox 36 had excess grease and less than 10mL of bath fluid came out of both sides combined.  My 2023 Fox36, had appropriate amounts of both grease and oil.

Months later i know but i'd forgotten about this. Oil levels ended up being appropriate but the internals of one side were loose. Ended up warrantying it (took a sram a solid month) and they gave me a new stanchion for the scratch and boxxer ultimate lowers :). Definitely going to be sending all new forks through the shop from now on.

I am presuming the lines about 1" from bottom of stanchion are light reflecting off oil, not a scratch. If a scratch, the oil is the least of your problems.
General answer is that is a concerning amount of oil. It has most likely come out of the damper from being stored upside down, but if oil is getting out the seals, dirt is getting into the fork.  Additionally, the lower oil bath is only 10ml of oil, so it if is lower bath oil, that volume is a concern.   Lack of oil, and dirt getting into the fork, is bad (think crossing the streams bad for the fork).
Personally, I would be scheduling a fork service sooner rather than later. If I had a ride planned before I could get it done, I would wipe the oil off and ride. However, if you do this and see no more oil, you have no idea if it is because the fork was upside down and is now perfectly OK, or because the oil ran out.
Given it is a new fork, there is a possibility of fault seals or assembly. Get it checked by a shop and discuss with them if a warranty repair is needed, and if so, if it is safe to leave till end of season (I suspect they will say no, and riding will void warranty).
